# Python - How to deal with an exception?

Tags: python, exception

My code gathers a bunch of URLS from a webpage, and then puts them into a list.

Once in a list, then it goes into each of them 1 by 1 and then performs a scrape.

However, some of the webpages, once accessed into, have a blank page which stops the code from executing the remainder of the URLS.

How can I add an exception or so to my code, that if this occurs, I can just bypass the webpage and continue into the next URL?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import pandas as pd
import requests
dataf=[]
val=[]
baseurl='https://careers.abbvie.com/'
endurl='?lang=en-us&previousLocale=en-US'

for x in range(1,89):
    driver.get(f'https://careers.abbvie.com/abbvie/jobs?page={x}&categories=Administrative%20Services%7CBusiness%20Development%7CGeneral%20Management%7CHEOR%2FMarket%20Access%7CInformation%20Technology%7CMarketing%7CMedical%7CRegulatory%20Affairs%7CSales%7CSales%20Support')
    time.sleep(7)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    eachRow = soup.find_all('p', class_='job-title')
    for link in eachRow:
        for links in link.find_all('a',href=True):
            val.append(baseurl+links['href']+endurl)
for b in val:
    try:
        driver.get(b)
        time.sleep(3)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        title=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jibe-container"]/div[2]/div/div/h1').text
        location=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-locations"]/span').text
        categories=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-categories"]/span').text
        jobID=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-req_id"]/span').text
        dict={"Title":title,"location":location,"categories":categories,"jobID":jobID,"URL":b}
        dataf.append(dict)
    except:
        print("hello")
df=pd.DataFrame(dataf)
df.to_csv('restasis.csv')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Comment: Your question now includes a ``try`` ``except``. Does that mean you know how to handle exceptions? What exactly are you asking about exception handling, then?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to wrap the lines that may throw the exception with `try/except` block

```
try:
  # do something that may throw
except Exception:
  # decide what to do (ignore? / print?)
```

Comment: I would try this, but at what block of my code would i put this in. Would it affect the dictionary i have listed in my code?

Comment: Share exception information so we can understand which part of the code throw it. It should not affect the dict you use in the code. But as I wrote  - we need the details in order to move on.

Comment: If the webpage is blank/exception occurs, I just want it to continue on to the next link in the list. So would a print("hello") be enough for this? under the exception?

Comment: @Age - you have 2 for loops that read data from web pages - which one raise the exception. Share the full details please.

Comment: lets assume (not sure its true) that `    driver.get(f'https://careers.abbvie.com/abbvie/jobs?page={x}&categories=Administrative%20Services%7CBusiness%20Development%7CGeneral%20Management%7CHEOR%2FMarket%20Access%7CInformation%20Technology%7CMarketing%7CMedical%7CRegulatory%20Affairs%7CSales%7CSales%20Support')` raise the exception  - wrap it with try/except and `continue` the loop